# Want to select distinct from 3 fields

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table with a town_id and 3 categories - cat1, cat2, cat3.

I need to be able to come up with a distinct list of all the categories in the table selected by town_id, not duplicated and in alphabetical order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question right, you need something like

```
SELECT [id_value] as town_id, cat
FROM
(
    SELECT cat1 AS cat, id_value AS town_id FROM table1 WHERE town_id = [id_value]
    UNION
    SELECT cat2, id_value FROM table1 WHERE town_id = [id_value]
    UNION
    SELECT cat3, id_value FROM table1 WHERE town_id = [id_value]
)a
```

[id_value] - chosen town_id. UNION by default is distinct; result of union as far as I remember will be sorted automatically in most implementations, but you may add `ORDER BY a.cat` to make it clear...

Taking the OP's comment context:

```
SELECT town_id AS [16], cat FROM 
(
  SELECT Category_id AS cat, id_value AS town_id 
   FROM establishments AS estab1 WHERE town_id = 16 
  UNION SELECT Category2_id, id_value
   FROM establishments AS etsab2 WHERE town_id = 16  
  UNION SELECT Category3_id, id_value 
   FROM establishments AS estab3 WHERE town_id = 16
) AS a;
```

Comment: SELECT 16 as town_id, establishments.category_id 
FROM
(
    SELECT Category_id AS cat FROM establishments AS estab1 WHERE town_id = 16
    UNION
    SELECT Category2_id FROM establishments AS etsab2 WHERE town_id = 16
    UNION
    SELECT Category3_id FROM establishments AS estab3 WHERE town_id = 16
)

Comment: but I am being told that "every derived table must have its own alias" which it seems to have

Comment: I've edited the answer in a way that I think fixes the problem, both in the original query and the invalid adoption the OP took. Feel free to edit it again to keep it your own.

Comment: Thanks for your help and giving me your time! I really appreciate all the help.